# how int converted to char automatically while working with FileInputStream in java

Tags: java, java-io

Here is sample code for copy file in java.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class FileCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String in = "D:\\test.txt";
        String out = "D:\\test_dup.txt";
        int i = 0;
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(in);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out)) {
            int b;
            while ((b = fis.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.println(b + "....." + (char) b);
                fos.write(b);
                i++;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("done" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

The content of file "test.txt" is "Welcome". When i run the program the contect get copied to second file and output of program is

```
87.....W
101.....e
108.....l
99.....c
111.....o
109.....m
101.....e
```

We use integer to hold intimidate result , how automatic conversion is happening from int to character when we write int to FileOutpurtStream? or where these automatic conversion like char to int while reading and int to char while writing is documented.

if [FileInputStream.read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()) method read a byte of data at a time , then why the return type is int instead of byte.

Comment: it is the ascii value of the char

Comment: Files on disk are just sequences of 8-bit integers (which we call "bytes"). If you open that file with a program that interprets these bytes as ASCII characters, then you see them as ASCII characters (whether they were intended to be seen as such, or not)

Comment: @anna about your edit, that's a completely different question. I suggest you open a new one about that.

Answer (score 4):

`write` writes bytes. So that's expected.

When it writes, e.g., `87` it doesn't write the characters `8` and `7`, it writes a byte whose value is 87, that happens to be ASCII `W`.